# Redirection should not lose the URL parameters

Tags: 7, rules, redirection

I have a rule and in condition I'm checking a path that if the current path is some path then in action I'm redirecting it to new url.

But the problem is that url has some parameters but in redirection it loses the parameters.

For example I have the following url:

```
first-url?param1=value1&param2=value2
```

and I want to redirect it to another url. But the url parameters should be append to the new url.

Is it possible in rules?

Answer (score 3):

To make the value of the URL argument available as new variable to Rules, you can use the [Rules URL Argument](https://www.drupal.org/project/rules_url_argument) module. Here is a quote about it (from its project page):

> ... provides two rules conditions based on URL arguments:
>
> - check if a URL argument is present.
> - compare the value of an URL argument.
>
> It also provides an action that makes the value of an URL argument available as new variable to Rules.

The newly provided Rules actions and conditions can be found under the "URL Argument" conditions and actions groups in the rule configuration interface.

For an example of how to use it, refer to [Comment # 3 in issue # 1686360](https://www.drupal.org/node/1686360#comment-6306112) which is about "*Pass an amount to the url, ie; site/content/node-title?amount=10 or /node-title?=amount:10*". Here is the relevant part of it:

> - add a "Check if URL argument exist" condition to your rule and set the "ARGUMENT" value to "amount".
> - add "Provide URL argument value" action to the rule and set "URL ARGUMENT NAME" value to "amount" and in the "Provided variables" section "ARGUMENT FROM URL - Variable name" to e.g. "`amount_from_url`".
>
> You will now be able to use the amount value as a variable "`amount-from-url`" for other actions in this rule.